# PHPMD and PHPCS Camelcase for Tests

Tags: phpmd, phpcs

I just installed both [PHPMD](https://phpmd.org/) and [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) with my Project.

Now, I would like to customize them a bit, but can't seem to achieve it.

I get 2 warnings that I would like to remove for all my project:

- phpcs: public method name `MyTests::my_test_that_should_pass` is not in camel caps format
- phpmd: the method `my_test_that_should_pass` is not in camel case

With PHPMD, I tried to change : `.composer/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/main/resources/rulesets/controversial.xml` and set `allow-underscore-test` to `true` like mentioned [here](https://phpmd.org/rules/controversial.html)

With PHPCS, I  don't really know how to do it.

Any idea???

https://phpmd.org/rules/controversial.html

Answer (score 8):

PHPCS uses a file called ruleset.xml to allow you to create your own custom standard. The documentation for it is here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-Ruleset

If you want a specific standard for your project, you can include a phpcs.xml file at the root of your project. It's exactly the same format as a ruleset.xml file and can even specify which files and folders need checking by default. Documentation for that is here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#using-a-default-configuration-file

I have no idea what coding standard you are using with PHPCS right now, but I'll assume you are using PSR2.

If you run `phpcs` with the `-s` option, you'll see an error message with an error code, like this: `Method name "MyTests::my_test_that_should_pass" is not in camel caps format (PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps)`. The code is the bit you need here.

For your custom standard, you want PSR2, but you don't want the `PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName` sniff because you obviously don't want PHPCS checking for camel case. So create a ruleset with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
    <description>My custom coding standard.</description>
    <rule ref="PSR2">
        <exclude name="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName"/>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Save that file and call it `ruleset.xml` or `phpcs.xml` and then run PHPCS using it: `phpcs /path/to/code --standard=/path/to/ruleset.xml`

Take a look at the annotated ruleset docs I linked at the top of the comment because there is a lot more you can do with those rulesets.